# How to get html tag from string in php?

Tags: php, html, dom, iframe

I have a html output I'm pulling from a RSS feed, it is somethig like this:

```
<div>
    <p>
        Some text
    </p>
    <iframe src="http://www.source.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

The problem is that I only need the attr "src" of the iframe tag, Is there a way to get it with PHP? Regex maybe?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php).

Something like this might give you the idea.

```
var_dump(simplexml_load_string($rss_feed));
```

Comment: I think DOMDocument is going to be a little more robust that SimpleXML if the HTML is not perfectly formed.  Also, I would guess you have to process the RSS and the HTML it contains separately as the HTML should be encoded into entities for the RSS to be correct.

Comment: If you only want the `src` attribute, you shouldn't need something *more robust*. IMO, SimpleXML's *simple* nature is right on in this case.

Comment: As I said, it's the HTML being invalid XML I'm concerned about.  Have a look at this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890120/php-processing-invalid-xml  if you still think it would be easier than just using DOMDocument which auto-corrects bad HTML.

Answer (score 4):

If you're consistently getting just the data you listed above, you could use a simple substring, using the string positions of `src="` and `"><iframe` to specify which substring you want:

```
$html = '<div><p>Some text</p><iframe src="http://www.source.com"></iframe></div>';

$start = strpos($html, 'src="') + 5;
$length = strpos($html, '"></iframe') - $start;
$src = substr($html, $start, $length);

echo $src;
```

**EDIT** - fixed the code and split into multiple lines.  This could easily be a one-liner, but - thought it was easier to understand if I broke into multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with regex, but a alternative way would be to use `explode` on the `"` marks and get `array[1]` like this:

```
$rssFeed = '<div>
    <p>
        Some text
    </p>
    <iframe src="http://www.source.com"></iframe>
</div>';

$rssArray = explode('"', $rssFeed);

echo $rssArray[1];
```

This requires your RSS feed to be very consistent though, if the "Some text" part were to contain `"` marks, this would mess up and you'd get a wrong string.

You could look through the array for everything starting with `http` or `www` to work around errors, but again, it requires a very consistent RSS feed, so you have to judge for you self if this would do the job good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse this output with a little command line perl script. This can be quite robust depending on how general you make the regular expression.

For example,

`$command = "echo your_html_output | perl -pe 's/src=\"(.*)\"/$1/'"; # Capture what is in between src=" and the " (the closing quote)`

`$output = shell_exec("$command");`