# XML ampersand error I have & in my xml file

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML file that updates every 24 hours when i have in the XML & or some anther char that is not legal to XML i have problem whit it how can i change the XML in javascript before i load it

XML:

```
 <deal>
      <title> ran & ban  </title>

</deal>
```

I know i need to change it to some thing like &
how  do I change the ROW data of the XML before i get it white

```
  function loadXMLDoc(filename){
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

}
else // code for IE5 and IE6
{
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhttp.open("GET",filename,true);
xhttp.send();

var xml= xhttp.responseXML;
 // xml==NULL 
}
```

Comment: Similar question in php - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890120/php-processing-invalid-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** This should do:

```
var xmlescape = (function() {


  var setup = {
    full  : 0, // encode ascii as well, 0|1
    names : 0, // use named char. entities, 0|1
  };

  var rfulltag =

      // match opening tag, capture tagname and full tag
      '(<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*>)' + 

     // capture everything not followed by a tag
     // (anything between matching pair of tags)
     '(?!\\s*<[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^>]*>)([\\s\\S]+?)' + 

    // capture closing tag coresponding to matched open tag
    '(<\\/\\2\\s*>)';

  rfulltag = new RegExp(rfulltag, 'gi'); // (g)lobal, case(i)nsensitive


  var runsafe = /["&\/<>']/g;   // reserved xml characters
  var rascii  = /[\x00-\xFF]/g; // ascii char.


  // hex character entities
  var unsafemap = {
    '"' : '&#x22;',
    '&' : '&#x26;',
    '/' : '&#x2F;',
    '<' : '&#x3C;',
    '>' : '&#x3E;',
    '\'': '&#x27;',
  };


  // named character entities
  var namedunsafemap = {
    '"' : '&quot;',
    '&' : '&amp;',
    '/' : '&sol;',
    '<' : '&lt;',
    '>' : '&gt;',
    '\'': '&apos;',
  };

  // use cache lookups to speed things a bit
  var cache = {};

  var pad02 = function(chr) {
    return (Array(3).slice(chr.length).join('0') + chr).toUpperCase();
  };

  var hexesc = function(chr) {
    return '&#x' + pad02(chr.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)) + ';';
  };

  // encode and cache
  var _encodeunsafe = function(chr) {
    return cache.hasOwnProperty(chr) ? cache[chr] : 
      (cache[chr] = (setup.full ? hexesc(chr) : (setup.names ? namedunsafemap[chr] : unsafemap[chr])));
  };

  var _encoder = function(all, _1, _2, _3, _4) {
    return _1 + _3.replace(setup.full ? rascii : runsafe, _encodeunsafe) + _4;
  };

  return function(sxml) {
    return ('' + sxml).replace(rfulltag, _encoder);
  };

})();

// xmlescape("<deal>  <title>  >>> \"<&> invalid b&d </&>' <<<  </title> <title>  ran &  ban </title>   </deal>");
// "<deal>  <title>  &#x3E;&#x3E;&#x3E; &#x22;&#x3C;&#x26;&#x3E; invalid b&#x26;d &#x3C;&#x2F;&#x26;&#x3E;&#x27; &#x3C;&#x3C;&#x3C;  </title> <title>  ran &#x26;  ban </title>   </deal>"


// from goog. closure
var parsexml = (function(g) {

  return ('function' == typeof g.DOMParser) ?
  // ffox, chrome, etc.
  function(xml) {
    return new g.DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
  } :
    (
    ('function' == typeof g.ActiveXObject) ? // ie

    (function(msaxo) {

      function _msdoc() {

        var doc = new msaxo('MSXML2.DOMDocument');

        if (doc) {

          // Prevent potential vulnerabilities exposed by MSXML2, see
          // http://b/1707300 and http://wiki/Main/ISETeamXMLAttacks for details.
          doc.resolveExternals = false;
          doc.validateOnParse  = false;

          // Add a try catch block because accessing these properties will throw an
          // error on unsupported MSXML versions. This affects Windows machines
          // running IE6 or IE7 that are on XP SP2 or earlier without MSXML updates.
          // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766391(VS.85).aspx for
          // specific details on which MSXML versions support these properties.
          try {

            doc.setProperty('ProhibitDTD', true);
            doc.setProperty('MaxXMLSize', 2 * 1024); // goog.dom.xml.MAX_XML_SIZE_KB
            doc.setProperty('MaxElementDepth', 256); // goog.dom.xml.MAX_ELEMENT_DEPTH

          } catch (e) {}
        }

        return doc;
      }

      return function(xml) {
        var doc;
        return doc = _msdoc(), doc.loadXML(xml), doc;
      };

    })(g.ActiveXObject) :

    // other
    function(xml) {
      throw Error(': poor xml support; upgrade');
    }
  );
})(window);


// use:

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
// send a request..

var xml = xhttp.responseXML || xhttp.responseText;

if ('string' == typeof xml)
  xml = parsexml(xmlescape(xml));


// eof
```

Comment: how to make it on an external file like abc.xml

Comment: read the file as plain text, filter it through the function, and parse it manualy.

Comment: ok, you might want to check tested utility libraries such as [underscrore](http://underscorejs.org/), [google closure](https://github.com/google/closure-library) and others, they already have a lot xml proccessing power built in.

Answer (score 3):

That 'XML' fragment you've posted *isn't* XML, and you will have to process it as a text file beforehand, since any compliant XML parser won't be able to parse this file. Note that this itself is potentially error-prone (beware of issues such as character-encoding), and ideally you need to have the incoming XML corrected to be [well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document) i.e.

```
 <deal>
      <title> ran &amp; ban  </title>

</deal>
```

See [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/beware-of-the-ampersand-when-using-xml/) for more information.

I would definitely push for your source to be corrected. If you have to code for correcting this, then likely

1. it'll have *other* errors (entity encoding or otherwise)
2. your 'correction' code will likely mess up when your source finally publish valid XML

Comment: @Brian Agnew I think that is the problem, i.e. the user is saying it's not valid when he gets it.  I would probably just read it into text and run a generic (internet code) function to strip out illegal characters (or ParseHTML) and THEN try and parse it.

Comment: Please note my first sentence re. processing it as a text file beforehand

Comment: can you give an example how to process it as a text file

Comment: Just open it as a 'normal' resource via HTTP (I'm afraid my Javascript isn't good enough to warrant an example posting on Stackoverflow)

Comment: Don't put up with garbage data. Complain loudly to whoever is producing this junk. If you can't trust the format, why should you trust the content? Would you try to repair it if it was Javascript that didn't compile?