# simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : Unescaped '&lt;' not allowed in attributes values

Tags: php, html, xml, laravel

First of all, I searched for this problem on the internet and could not find a solution, although there are people who have faced the same problem.

My error is:

> `simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : Unescaped '&lt;' not allowed in attributes values`

My problem is that I get this error while reading an xml file from e-commerce site with PHP.  Below you can see the xml line where the error is occured.

```
<Product Id="" ModelCode="" Sku="" Gtin="" Name="" 
         ShortDescription="" 
         FullDescription="<p>XXXXXXXXXX<br/>XXXXXXXX<br/>XXXXXXXX</p>"
>
```

I think the problem is caused by `<p>` and `<br>` tags in FullDescription field. But I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: You're dealing with actual invalid XML, best course would be to guarantee they are valid. If you can't, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890120/php-processing-invalid-xml) a possible solution.

Comment: Same problem as [on your recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496821/simplexml-load-string-entity-line-18-parser-error-entity-nbsp-not-defin/69498807#69498807) it seems.

Comment: The solution here is not an answer to my other question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `<` and `>` characters in `FullDescription` attribute value as `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively:

```html
<Product ...
  FullDescription="&lt;p&gt;XXXXXXXXXX&lt;br/&gt;XXXXXXXX&lt;br/&gt;XXXXXXXX&lt;/p&gt;">
```

You can try to use the code below to fix attributes including HTML tags as a best guess (it assumes UTF-8 charset by default which should be fine with XML):

```php
$xml = preg_replace_callback(
    '/="([^"]*<[^"]*)"/',
    function(array $matches) {
        return '="'.htmlspecialchars($matches[1]).'"';
    },
    $xml
);
```

Comment: There are thousands of rows like this. I can't change them all one by one

Comment: Is there a way I can ignore the < and > characters after the first <

Comment: updated my post